# Como inserir dados em uma tabela com relacionamentos no postgresql

Tags: sql, inserir

Bom dia, estou fazendo um trabalho acadêmico no qual preciso pegar um banco de dados e recriá-lo no postgresql, porém, há 3 tabelas que possuem FK e constraints que me impedem de inserir os dados nelas. Segue abaixo o conceito lógico do banco de dados e as PK e FK que estão me atrapalhando:
[Modelo Lógico do Banco de Dados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Xvc.png)

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte:

```
INSERT INTO departamentos (id_departamento, nome, id_localizacao, id_gerente)
VALUES (10, 'Administration', 1700, 200);
```

e aparece o seguinte erro: ERROR:  insert or update on table "departamentos" violates foreign key constraint "empregados_departamentos_fk"
DETAIL:  Key (id_gerente)=(200) is not present in table "empregados".
SQL state: 23503

Detalhe: Quando o valor do gerente é nulo, a query é realizada com sucesso.
Imagino que eu não possa inserir um id_gerente (que é basicamente o id_empregado[PK]) sem antes ter inserido os dados dos funcionários, mas quando vou inserir os dados na tabela funcionários recebo o mesmo erro, pois ela precisa dos dados do departamento. Qual a solução para isso? Tirar as constraints?

Meu primeiro post aqui, desculpa qualquer coisa!

Comment: *"insert or update on table "departamentos" violates foreign key constraint "empregados_departamentos_fk"* isso significa que precisa primeiro inserir os dados na tabela para onde existe a *foreign key*, ai provavelmente a tabela que tem os dados de "gerente", e assim por diate... pra facilitar, insira primeiro os dados nas tabelas que não tem *foreign key* e depois nas outras

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Salve, Pipec4t!

Há um semibug aí, que talvez seja parte do seu trabalho. É o seguinte:

De fato, o modelo de banco de dados parece estar de acordo com o negócio, com a entidade do mundo real: todo departamento realmente tem um gerente (que é um empregado), e todo empregado está vinculado a um departamento.

Contudo, se ambos forem dados obrigatórios, você não vai ter como iniciar o preenchimento do seu BD, porque não vai ter um empregado para criar um departamento nem um departamento para criar o empregado. É como uma síndrome do ovo ou da galinha, um paradoxo lógico.

A solução, especialmente pensando no mundo real, a meu ver seria permitir que o gerente de um departamento seja nulo (representando a situação em que o cargo esteja vago, o que eventualmente pode acontecer, mesmo).

Aí você poderia fazer em três operações:

1. Criar o departamento, passando nulo como gerente nulo,
2. Depois poderia criar empregados vinculados a este departamento -- e, por fim,
3. Vincular um desses empregados no campo de gerente do departamento.

Mas realmente, não faria as três coisas de uma só vez, não.